# Kubernetes Ingress Redirect and Rewrite

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

quick question as I am sure its an easy fix, just cannot seem to figure it out!

We have a site that runs on [www.awesomeapp.com](http://www.awesomeapp.com) - all working perfectly on ingress routing

However I want to also redirect the route domain to [www.awesomeapp.com](http://www.awesomeapp.com) for example awesomeapp.com => [www.awesomeapp.com](http://www.awesomeapp.com)

I added this annotation
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://www.awesomeapp.com

Again all working perfectly.

My question is how do I also get the path added as well. For example

user enters in awesomeapp.com/myawesomepage and what I want is it to not only redirect but append the path as well so it ends up like this

[www.blahblah.com/myawesomepage](http://www.blahblah.com/myawesomepage)

I added this ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1$2 but this does not work, and that is in conjunction with this - path: /(/|$)(.*)

Full yaml config as follows:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:  
    name: root-routing
    labels:
      app: awesomeapp
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx     
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: https://www.awesomeapp.com
        ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1$2
spec:
    tls:
    - hosts:
        - awesomeapp.com
      secretName: awesomeapp-com-tlscert
    rules:
    - host: awesomeapp.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
                name: awesomeapp
                port:
                    number: 80
```

Thanks
John

Comment: Have you seen [this example](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/)?

Comment: Yes, but does not quite apply to this situation as the domain is changing as well, well not the domain per say but the root to www.

Comment: Could you remove the permanent redirect and verify it it works without it?

Comment: Hi there, nope. Just to confirm it now looks like this.         
ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: https://www.awesomeapp.com/$2

Comment: Instead of the perma redirect it would be better to use [from/to www](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#redirect-fromto-www). As for teh rewrite: I see nothing to rewrite here actually but first try to adjust the `path` and the `rewrite`. For example: `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /myawesomepage` and `path: /(.*)`

Answer (score 1):

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
return 301 https://www.awesomeapp.com$request_uri;

Comment: Could you describe your actions taken with more details?